# Adding raw_inputs into this lesson on Codecademy

Tags: python

First timer here just beginning to teach myself python on Codecademy. I have a question about an exercise I completed

```
def hotel_cost(days):
  return 140 * (days - 1)

def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == "Charlotte":
    return 183
  elif city == "Tampa":
    return 220
  elif city == "Pittsburgh":
    return 222
  elif city == "Los Angeles":
    return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days * 40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50
  elif days >= 3:
    cost -= 20
  return cost

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
  return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days - 1) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money

print trip_cost("Charlotte", 5, 500)
```

The above code about planning a trip works and makes sense to me. What I want to try to figure out for fun before continuing on to the next lesson is how I can add raw_inputs so that instead of inputting the values in print trip_cost on the last line I can have something like this

```
city = raw_input("where are you going? ")
days = raw_input("how many days are you staying? ")
spending_money = raw_input("how much spending money are you bringing? ")
```

I can't seem to figure out how to integrate that into the code. Any help? I know this is super basic but just getting my feet wet.

Comment: I don't want to come across as awful but I'm not sure that this is the best resource for learning. For a start, it's using Python 2.7 which will soon be redundant. I'm also not sure why it's covering functions before `raw_input`. Those are failings of the tutorial, not yours.

Comment: @roganjosh They did go over some basic raw_input stuff earlier in lessons. Do you not suggest using codecademy as my first way to get some experience? I've never done any sort of programming before and this is the first language I'm learning

Comment: I'm not going to suggest a source to learn from because I think people learn in different ways, but I will say that that learning Python 2 [is outdated](https://pythonclock.org/) and that I don't think they are giving you a logical progression into programming. As you go through the course, just keep that in mind. I wish you the best of luck, you won't luck back once you can program :)

Comment: I know you said you won't suggest a source, but advice would be helpful. Basically I've been working in finance and interested into more of a data analytics direction, and many jobs want you to know SQL and Python. So I'm trying to get my skills where it would be accurate to put them on my resume under skills. Like I said, I've never done any programming in my life and just trying to learn python

Comment: I can sympathise with that, I had a similar situation. I started with Learn Python the Hard Way (which was free, but now he seems to have pay-walled it, and is a controversial character). A suggestion I hate myself saying; continue with your course as long as it seems useful and store your questions up. If they're not answered by the end of the course, there's a good chance they have been answered here so hone your Googling skills. Even once you know the basis of a language or libraries, you'll be Googling for life, you just cannot remember all the info, but you can remember how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right just add this:

```
def hotel_cost(days):
  return 140 * (days - 1)

def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == "Charlotte":
    return 183
  elif city == "Tampa":
    return 220
  elif city == "Pittsburgh":
    return 222
  elif city == "Los Angeles":
    return 475
  else:
    return 0

def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days * 40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50
  elif days >= 3:
    cost -= 20
  return cost

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
  return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days - 1) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money

city = raw_input("where are you going? ")
days = int(raw_input("how many days are you staying? "))
spending_money = int(raw_input("how much spending money are you bringing? "))
print trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)
```

Comment: does it matter where within the code i insert it? I got an error when putting it all at the end

Comment: it asks me "Where are you going", then I type in Los Angeles and then i get this:                                                                                                               where are you going? Los Angeles
how many days are you staying? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 26, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Los Angeles'

Comment: @Vin It seems like you typed 'Los Angeles' to the second answer. Anyway.
I updated my answer.

Comment: Well your code does work now. I'll have to look into the comparison later between the two and see where I went wrong. I appreciate the quick help!!